# Performant way of creating a custom method signature with Byte Buddy

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I'm trying to implement a Profiler with ByteBuddy. I'm currently struggling with efficiently creating a proper signature of the methods I'm profiling.

Here is a gist of my current implementation: https://gist.github.com/felixbarny/e0c64819c59368a28200

There are two implementations for the ProfilingInterceptor.profile method. Each one has its own flaw.

The first one uses `@Origin String signature` as the signature. This is very efficient as ByteBuddy seems to cache that. The problem is, that I'm not happy with the format of the signature. For example `method2(I)I`.

In the second implementation I'm injecting `@Origin(cacheMethod = true) Method method` and manually constructing a nicer looking signature: `int org.stagemonitor.benchmark.profiler.ClassJavassistProfiled.method2(int)`. The obvious problem is that the signature is re-created on every invocation - not performant (my jmh benchmarks say it's slower by a factor of 4).

Is there a way to cache the signature for example by creating a string constant for each signature?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I gave this some thought, I am going to change the String origin to resemble the Method's toString value from the next version on.

Comment: It would be cool to have a `@Signature` annotation which can be used to select a specific signature format via an enum. That way, you could also stay backwards compatible by not changing the signature format that you get with `@Origin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to implement your own annotation and create a binding. Any such `String` value is then added to the class's constant pool and simply returned from there.

You can find an [example for creating a custom annotation](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) at the bottom of the Byte Buddy tutorial. For implementing a custom `@Signature` annotation, you would do the following:

```
enum SignatureBinder
    implements TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder.ParameterBinder<StringValue> {

  INSTANCE; // singleton

  @Override
  public Class<Signature> getHandledType() {
    return Signature.class;
  }

  @Override
  public MethodDelegationBinder.ParameterBinding<?> bind(AnnotationDescription.Loaded<StringValue> annotation,
      MethodDescription source,
      ParameterDescription target,
      Instrumentation.Target instrumentationTarget,
      Assigner assigner) {
    if (!target.getTypeDescription().represents(String.class)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(target + " makes illegal use of @Signature");
    }
    StackManipulation constant = new TextConstant("<signature goes here>");
    return new MethodDelegationBinder.ParameterBinding.Anonymous(constant);
  }
}
```

The `MethodDescription` object named `source` describes the intercepted method and offers an interface that resembles the `Method` class. You would then register this binder with the `MethodDelegation` and you could use the annotation in the delegant thereafter.

On a side note: I would avoid using canonical names. Those name could be conflicting, e.g. the classes

```
foo.Bar$Qux
foo.Bar.Qux
```

with `Bar` being once a class with an inner class `Qux` and once being a package with a class `Qux` have the same name. I know it is unlikely, but you never know how user code is going to look like.